# How to search, insert, remove nodes in AVL trees when the key is a string

Tags: c, tree, avl-tree

I have a program that reads in strings from a text file and then stores them in an AVL tree, I also have to remove nodes and insert new ones from the command line.
I understand how to do this when the nodes have ints as keys, but mine are strings.

How should I tackle this?

```
typedef struct Node {
    int height;
    int count;
    char key[10];
    struct Node * left;
    struct Node * right;
} Node;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I understand how to do this when the nodes have ints as keys, but mine
>   are strings.

The same, you just need to change the comparison function (compare strings instead of integers), something like:

```
static int comp_by_key(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const Node *a = pa, *b = pb;

    return strcmp(a->key, b->key);
}
```